# dynamic UI components in phonegap applications

Tags: android, cordova

i am trying to develop an android application using phonegap. i have kept a flag in local storage. depending on if the flag is set or not, i want to show a different page. for example, if the flag is set to true, i want to show a message on the screen, and if the flag is set to false, i want to show a couple of text boxes and a button. how can i modify the html part according to this flag value?

```
if(flag == true)
    //show message in UI
else
   //show buttons in UI
```

also, are different pages required for this purpose or can it be done programmatically using javascript or jQuery?

Comment: No need to create different page simply add controls via jquery

Comment: thanks. am able to modify using jQuery..:)